# Right-to-left language in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, right-to-left

I am writing an application which requires me to identify text in arabic language and create a small progress bar that moves from right to left telling the user where exactly he is.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFxZP.png]

Two things:
1) I don't know how to make a progress bar move from right to left
2) if at all I am planning to use Fillrect, I want to identify if there is a text else don't fill rectangle.

For English text, we can do a character count but for foreign language how can we make out if the LabelField contains text or not

Comment: doesn't `labelField.getText().length() == 0` work in any language?  am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: yeahh ur logic is right....we get the length as say 96...but how can u differentiate where there is space and where the word is ending

Comment: ah, I see.  that's a more difficult problem :)

Comment: Are u reading the data from xml?

Comment: yes and the xml is like this <Text = "Arabic wr" verse="0" duration="55"/>

Comment: I think it would help if you presented the code that does what you want for English text, and then explain how it breaks when using right-to-left text, like Arabic or Hebrew.

Comment: @MichaelDonohue i have added an image for reference. I want to make a progress bar move from right to left depending on the text and it want to stop after it reaches end of line. I have created the bar now. after end of first line, I want it to reach second line and start from right to left again.....hope i am clear...if not, i am happy to be more clearer

Comment: so for this,I need to know where the sentence ends and suppose the second line has only two words, the bar should load only half the width of screen and jump to next screen